# Can Checkstyle target a specific file when run through Maven?

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle

**Background**

I have a Maven project with Checkstyle.

I run `mvn checkstyle:check` to run Checkstyle against all project files.

I want to run it against a specific file.

As an example, I want to run it against `src/main/java/MyClass.java`.

**The following works:**

```
mvn checkstyle:check -Dcheckstyle.includes="**\/MyClass.java"
```

But if I had any other classes with the same name elsewhere in the codebase, it would also check those. This is unfortunate.

**The following does NOT work:**

```
mvn checkstyle:check -Dcheckstyle.includes="src/main/java/MyClass.java"
```

It simply succeeds, telling me I have 0 errors. And for the record, it has errors. So it's clearly not checking that file.

**Question**

How can I adjust this command to run Checkstyle against a specific file given by its path, without using wildcards?

Comment: [this method](https://codehaus-plexus.github.io/plexus-utils/apidocs/org/codehaus/plexus/util/FileUtils.html#getFiles(java.io.File,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) is called ["behind the scenes"](https://github.com/apache/maven-checkstyle-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/checkstyle/exec/DefaultCheckstyleExecutor.java) ..but javadoc is also "thin" on these :)

Comment: [Ant patterns](https://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns)!! of source files (relatively to src/main/java(, src/test/java, src/main/resources ...);) ..so `-Dincludes=MyClass.java` could do the job..in your case (but "default package" is badong)

Comment: You should mark this answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the parameter with the right syntax:

```
mvn checkstyle:check -Dincludes="src/main/java/MyClass.java"
```

For further information: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/check-mojo.html

Comment: I needed to do `-Dcheckstyle.includes`.

Comment: @EllenSpertus Yes, you can use the "user property" instead of the "parameter". I needed to execute the command using double quotes, 
maybe it's a problem of system's default encoding:   

`mvn "checkstyle:check" "-Dincludes=src/main/java/MyClass.java"`


This is working with maven 3.8.6, Windows and plugin version 3.3

Answer (score 2):

I am visiting this question after a couple of years so here is what I did to make it work:

```bash
 mvn checkstyle:check -Dcheckstyle.includes="**\/Foo.java"
```

As mentioned in the previous answer, you can refer to the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/check-mojo.html#includes) for more details.

Here is what you need to know about the property `checkstyle.includes`:

> Specifies the names filter of the source files to be used for Checkstyle.

```
Type: java.lang.String  
Required: Yes  
User Property: checkstyle.includes  
Default: **\/*.java
```

Answer (score -1):

The path should be relative to your [source directory](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/check-mojo.html#sourceDirectories).

This uniquely identifies the single file `src/main/java/MyClass.java` as it doesn't use a wildcard path.

```
mvn checkstyle:check -Dcheckstyle.includes="MyClass.java"
```

More typically you would be using java packages to namespace your classes.

```
mvn checkstyle:check -Dcheckstyle.includes="com/example/myapp/MyClass.java"
```